# How can I change my Mic-in in port

Tags: sound, microphone

I am having Problem with my Mic-in port. Can I change my mic-in port to line-in port so that if I connect my microphone to line-in port it will receive voice?

In windows, if I connect any speaker or microphone a window pop-up and ask me what type of device I have connected to that port. Is there any way to do this on ubuntu so that I can use line-in port of my PC as microphone in.

Thanks in advanced and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the sound icon near your name (right top corner) and select "Sound Preferences", then check you **Inputs** tab.

[image]

**Edit**

You should be able to use your line-in port by selecting it in the **Inputs**->**Connector** list.

[image]

Comment: Sorry to say that I am not asking for it. I am asking that is it possible to use my line-in port as a microphone(in) port?

Comment: Hope the edit has made things more clear.